# PHP function override?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following situation of being between two versions of PHP during development. I've temporarily done the following below:

```
$oldphp = getdbVersion();
if($oldphp)
{
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Is there anyway to override these functions so you can call the new name but the old name is called automatically so the code would only have:

```
 mysqli_query ($sql);
```

but would see the correct function based on the server version?

I ended up using a wrapper so code checking doesn't need to be all over the place to check if the function exists:

```
function _mysql_query($connection, $findrecords)
{
   if(check_sql_version())
   {
      $result = mysql_query($findrecords);
   }
   else
   {
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $findrecords);
   }
   if( ! $result)
   {
      die('Invalid query: ' . (check_sql_version())? mysql_error():mysqli_error());
   }
   return $result;
 }
```

Comment: You cannot simply replace the old `mysql_...()` functions like that. Both connectors require different usage if you want to do things right.

Comment: You can just use wrapper classes and forget about the db altogether (any ORM system like Doctrine, etc.)

Comment: you run a php older than 5.0? mysqli is available from php 5.0.

Comment: What does `getdbVersion()` do, actually?

Comment: what others are saying... you should be using an abstraction layer... so that your code is extension agnostic.

Comment: Yeah it's 5.4 but it doesn't like any sqli function calls. I've confirmed this multiple times.

Comment: getdbVersion just gets the php version. If it's less than 5.5 it reverts to standard sql calls whereas higher than 5.5 goes to the sqli calls if I read the documentation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Appaprently [you can override PHP built-in functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) (using [APD extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/apd)), but you should really have a good use case when that's something that you would want to do. The one in the question is **not** one such case.

If you need to support both mysql and mysqli extensions, than you should abstract database interaction using a set of classes and adapters, where each adapter implements a common interface used to interact with the database. There are many database abstraction libraries available, and you will probably find a one that meets your system requirements, while still providing access methods via both mysql and mysqli extensions.

ADODB is one of the classics. Being a legacy library itself, it will most probably work with the old versions of PHP that you have to support, while still being able to use mysqli extension as well. Docs are here:

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to define wrappers for all the functions, there's a good example of how to do that [here](http://mysql.dotpointer.com). In that case it provides backward compatibility, this is very useful if you have lots of legacy code you want to run in a newer version of PHP. However your situation is the opposite. You should be developing using mysqli provisioning a forward comparability shim.

To invoke the (forward) shim, simply...

```
if(!function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
    require_once 'mysqli.inc,.php';
}
```

However I'm not aware of an existing forward shim for mysqli.